# I've error with this selector when I'm using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm using node, express, cheerio and axios to create a simple web scraper. In this example, axios has data but after loading data with cheerio I've this error:

`(node:14056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: content.forEach is not a function`

Scraper code:

```js
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  axios('https://fake.com/users')
  .then(response => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(response);
    let users = $('.users .user');
    console.log(cards);
  });
});
```

But why has this error? because I'm passing data after resolve the promise in then block??

Comment: where is forEach loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used `response` and you have to use `response.data` instead:

`let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);`

Actually `response` returns all response has received from server, but `response.data` returns only data that has received from API.